# How can I actually remove New tags from Start Menu in Windows 10 20H2?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am using Windows 10 version 20H2 Professional Edition (x86_64), and I have installed many programs (`appwiz.cpl` currently says there are 146 programs installed, and I am going to install hundreds (300+) more), I am very adept in using Windows and I don't normally use Start Menu, but some programs don't create desktop icons, instead they only create Start Menu icons (of course I know where they are installed), so in order to launch them quickly without navigating to their full path I have to use start menu, and I find the "highlight newly installed programs" feature really annoying...

I will provide a screenshot to illustrate the problem more vividly:

[image]

This is only a small fragment of my Start Menu, almost all of them are highlighted because I very rarely click start menu icons, I can confirm clicking on the icons removes the highlights, but can you imagine me clicking on hundreds of these icons just to remove the highlights?

Of course I tried to Google search for a solution, and though this time it did return something relevant out of way many more irrelevant results, the method I found is useless/outdated and doesn't work anymore.

The method I found is creating a registry REG_DWORD value with value of 0 named Start_NotifyNewApps at the path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, in PowerShell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name Start_NotifyApps -Type DWord -Value 0
```

Then restart the computer.

But the value was already set so before the last time I rebooted my computer:

[image]

Yet as you see it didn't achieve what it was supposed to achieve...

So How can I remove the New highlights without clicking on all those icons?

---

***Update***

After more futile research I have made a few more tweaks:

[image]

Yet those highlights are still there...

---

I have manually removed some of the highlights while `procmon` is up, after setting the filter to `ProccessName is StartMenuExperienceHost.exe then Include` and `Operation is RegSetValue then Include`, I have discovered something:

[image]

So `StartMenuExperienceHost.exe` writes changes to a REG_BINARY value named Data located at path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\$de${5ea67f6a-4003-47f7-8f3f-bee782d746be}$$windows.data.unifiedtile.roamedtilepropertiesmap\Current
```

This is mine's path, I believe the guid might be different on another computer but the path should be like this.

Unfortunately the value is REG_BINARY and I can't properly parse the value, so I can't programmatically simulate the effect of right clicking on all those icons, that would be way above me, but there might be something I have missed that are easier to do, setting the filter to include `StartMenuExperienceHost.exe` displays 7327 events out of 2.15 million plus events, I have dumped the filtered events and uploaded to Google Drive:

[Logfile.PML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18t32PtKXo6k8MGZBNjBox52yUKWvNks3/view?usp=sharing)

---

Actually this particular REG_BINARY value is encoded in ASCII, so I am able to parse it, I will parse it now...

---

So I used the following codes to parse the value, I first got data.txt, the results were too cryptic and contains many control characters, so I programmatically removed the control characters (except line breaks) and saved as data_plain.txt, the results are more human readable but it still contains nonsense characters:

```
$data=(get-itemproperty 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\$de${5ea67f6a-4003-47f7-8f3f-bee782d746be}$$windows.data.unifiedtile.roamedtilepropertiesmap\Current').Data
$data=($data | %{[char]$_}) -join ''
$data > C:\data.txt
$data -replace '[\x00-\x09]|[\x0B-\x0C]|[\x0E-\x1F]|\x7F' > C:\data_plain.txt
```

[data.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18mwxJvLZ0_X03AuA5QyZlL6RdxUbDT_V/view?usp=sharing)

[data_plain.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k3CM8l7Vs23YYjDjSlW_R1Sl157cXAl5/view?usp=sharing)

The next step should be statistically determine the meaning of the babbles using frequency.

Comment: I can successfully remove "Recently Added items" as you tried in your post. Having done that, I do not know what the impact of making further registry changes might be. That may have hampered the Windows setting - I am not sure.

Comment: Just wondering if any Microsoft docs page may cover this.